# Validate form with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have here a register HTML form with some elements. I need to validate the elements on server side and client side and I will explain why. For example, in HTML form I have:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    User name:<input type="text" name="user_name"/><br/>
    Email:<input type="text" name="user_email"/><br/>
    Password:<input type="text" name="user_password"/><br/>
</form>
```

I use PHP to check if the email and user already exists in the database. And I can use PHP to identify if the input fields are empty too.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];

    $exists = "";
    $sql = "SELECT user_name from users WHERE user_name = '{$user_name}' LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($num == 1) 
    {
        $exists .= "u";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT user_email from users WHERE user_email = '{$user_email}' LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($num == 1)
    {
        $exists .= "e";
    }

    if (empty($user_name) || empty($user_email) || empty($user_password))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Please fill all input fields to register!');</script>";
    }
    else if($exists == "u")
    {
        echo "<script>alert('This user is already registered in our system.');</script>";
    }
    else if($exists == "e")
    {
        echo "<script>alert('This email is already registered in our system.');</script>";
    }
    else if($exists == "ue")
    {
        echo "<script>alert('This user and this email are already registered in our system.');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        //Here insert the values in database
    }
}
```

Looks perfect, except for one thing: when I click submit the page is refreshed and all the input fields values are cleaned. This is bad because the user will have to enter all informations again because something was wrong. I know that the reason for this is because I am validating the form after sending it with PHP. To overcome this problem I need to validate the fields before sending the form, logically using JavaScript in the client side. But how about the check in the database? I will need to use PHP for that. If I did not have to check the database I could use JavaScript only. I would have to mix the validations with JavaScript and PHP, I think for that I should use AJAX, but do not know how.

Comment: please mention HTML part as well, it must be with `form` tag

Comment: you can do this validation in client side before submit data.

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain By client side would be the best option. But I use PHP to check if the email and user already exists in the database. I would have to mix the validations with JavaScript and PHP, I think for that I should use AJAX, but do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do the check at the client level (javascript) not in php but hey if you insists try this

```
if ($_POST["password_user"] != $_POST["confirm_password"]) 
   echo "<script>alert('The entered passwords doesn't match. Try again.'); 
       document.getElementByID('inputPassword').value = $_POST['password_user']; 
       document.getElementByID('inputConfirmPassword').value = $_POST['confirm_password']; 
       </script>";
```

Also update your HTML input to have ids

```
Password:<font color="red">*</font> 
<input id="inputPassword" type="password" name="password_user"/><br/>
Confirm password:<font color="red">*</font> 
<input id="inputConfirmPassword" type="password" name="confirm_password"/><br/>
```

Edit:

Added good AJAX tutorial:

- [without JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)
- [with JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (I personally find this easier to use)

Edit2:

Sample code for PHP (server side) that returns a JSON to be fed back to the client (javascript)

```
<?php
$canLogin = false;
$responseArray = array();
// your logic here
// ....
if ($canLogin)
{
    $responseArray["status"] = "Success";        
} else
{
    //Use the appropriate HTTP header (default 200), this is sometimes missed by developers  
    http_response_code(404); 
    $responseArray["status"] = "Error";
}

return json_encode($responseArray);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, client side would be the best option. But I use PHP to check if the email and user already exists in the database. I would have to mix the validations with JavaScript and PHP, I think for that I should use AJAX, but do not know how.

Comment: You can try to see the links in my updated answer. I just updated it :)

Comment: Validation should almost always be done on the server - any client-side validation layer is normally additional and just cosmetic. Client-side validation, of course, can be bypassed, leaving your server vulnerable if you don't also validate on there. AJAX is the common means of merging the two disciplines.

Comment: Agree with @Utkanos, While critical validation can happen at the server, sometimes client side validation can be arguably quite complex too . I just updated my answer again with samples for PHP script on the server side